# Did Anton, Bivens, and Davis make a mistake here (in Calculus)?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am having this book for Calculus. I am reviewing stuffs on abs. Max and min.

Here is what I think is a mistake by the three authors: a question asks to find the relative extrema, if at all, for $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2-x}$ on $(0,1)$. The first derivative came out to be $f'(x)=-\frac{2x-1}{(x^2-x)^2}$. **Here** my book says "although $f$ is not differentiable at $x=0,1$, these values are **doubly** disqualified since they are neither in the domain of $f$ nor in the interval $(0,1)$."

But aren't we supposed to include points of non-differentiability when finding the values of abs. Extrema?

Comment: Not if they are not points where we have defined $f$, no.

Comment: I think the authors compare this situation to the situation where you would have wanted to find the extrema on a bounded and *closed* interval, say $[a,b]$. Then you would have had to investigate the values of the function at the extremities of the interval. But in this case, you want an extremum in the *open* interval $(a,b)$, so you don't care about the values at $a$ and $b$ of $f$. Moreover $f$ is not even *defined* at those points so it would not make sense to check the values of $f$ there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non-differentiability is *not* a reason to exclude a point in the domain of a function from among those where one looks for extreme values.  The only reason to exclude $0$ and $1$ is that they are not in the domain.

Comment: Ok, I think I am confused as to what type of non-differentiability the authors refer to.

Comment: I was thinking the case where if the point is not in the domain of the original function, the derivative for that point will also not exist, thus non-differentiability.